# How to handle "Raw types usage" warning while sending raw ResponseEntity from Controllers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, sonarlint

I have a simple APIs that initiates some action on records and return a 200 response:

```
    /**
     * Initiate some workflow.
     *
     * @param recordsBulkInitiate records to initiate
     * @return {@link ResponseEntity}
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "initiate workflow")
    @PostMapping("/initiate")
    public ResponseEntity bulkInitiateRecords(@RequestBody InitiateBulkRecordsDto recordsBulkInitiate) {
        workflowService.bulkInitiate(recordsBulkInitiate);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(OK);
    }

    /**
     * Submit some workflow action on arecord
     *
     * @param workflowActionDto the record action data
     * @return {@link ResponseEntity}
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "action taken by user")
    @PostMapping("/action")
    public ResponseEntity submitAction(@RequestBody WorkflowActionDto workflowActionDto) {
        log.info("submit action on record [{}]", workflowActionDto);
        workflowService.submitRecordAction(workflowActionDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(OK);
    }
```

Both Sonarlint and intellij throws warnings: "Raw types should not be used".

How should I handle this warning? For now, I'm just using `ResponseEntity<Object>` which seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `ResponseEntity<?>` instead of `ResponseEntity` on your method signature return type:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> submitAction(@RequestBody WorkflowActionDto workflowActionDto)
```

You can avoid IDE warnings, but they are actually the same, compiler would replace it with generic type, so `ResponseEntity<?>` and `ResponseEntity` are the same.

**EDIT:**

As I see you are returning `ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK)`, so you are returning a body of type `HttpStatus`. So you can be more explicit in your methode signature by using `ReponseEntity<HttpStatus>`.

Comment: I got another warning: "remove usage of generic wildcard type" :)

Comment: In your question, what is the value of OK please?

Comment: It's an enum provided by `HttpStatus` class

Comment: The parameter of ok method of ResponseEntity should be the body of the response, so it's the same type of the generic type in ResponseEntity, so you can just use ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> in the method signature.